# Pertubational approach of a scalar field EOM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, perturbation-theory, classical-field-theory

I am trying to understand a calculation in a QFT textbook.

Given the equation of motion of a scalar field $h$
\begin{align}
\Box h - \lambda h^2 - J = 0
\end{align}
I now want to solve this equation pertubatively in $\lambda$.
So for $\lambda = 0$ i obviously get $\Box h_0 = J$. Now the autor
uses the approach $h = h_0 + h_1$ where $h_1 = \mathcal O (\lambda^1)$.

I dont get why we would do that. First of all, aren't we using superposition in this approach? Which is confusing me, since the EoM is not linear in this case, and why we would say that $h_1$ is of linear order of $\lambda$? I am new to pertubation theory so if somebody could share an inshight, it would really help me.

**Note:** I know that in QM for example we often try to split a hamiltonian in an unperturbed and a perturbed hamiltonian. But i can not connect the method used in QM with the method used in this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the perturbation is quadratic we can not say that the full operator is linear, howeveryou can take as an Ansatz the same decomposition of $h$ as usual:
$$h = h^{(0)}+\lambda h^{(1)} + \lambda^2h^{(2)}+\cdots$$
and each order is smaller because by assumption $\lambda\ll 1$, while checking what are the conditions needed. If one then solves for the $h^{(n)}$ order by order, one expects to obtain a better approximation to the exact solution.
Meaning:
$h^{(0)}$ solves the equation $\mathcal{0}_0h^{(0)} = 0$ and then $h^{(1)}$ will have to solve the equation obtained by replacing our Ansatz 
$$\square \left(h^{(0)}+\lambda h^{(1)} + \lambda^2h^{(2)}+\cdots \right) -\lambda \left( h^{(0)}+\lambda h^{(1)} + \lambda^2h^{(2)}+\cdots\right)^2 = 0$$
and collecting the order 1 terms in $\lambda$ leads to,
$$\square h^{(0)}+\lambda\square h^{(1)} -\lambda {h^{(0)}}^2 - 2\lambda^2 h^{(0)} h^{(1)} - \lambda^3 {h^{(1)}}^2 + \cdots = 0 $$
The first term is cero because the 0-th order already solves that and the last two terms are higher order in $\lambda$ so we neglect them and in include them in the next order corrections. So for the 1-st order you get
$$\square h^{(1)} - \lambda {h^{(0)}}^2 =0$$
and so on and so forth. When you have achieved the level of precision desired, you then solve the inhomogeneous problem ($J\neq 0$) by traditional methods, for example convoluting your solution with the source.

So one is not formally using superposition in this case, but suggesting a form for the solution and finding which equation should then correspond to each term in the suggested expansion.

Comment: But $\mathcal O _\lambda h$ is not equal the EoM because of the $h^2$-term ?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_\lambda h$ is the EoM, the $\lambda$ in my Ansatz is just playing the role of book-keeping the orders.

Comment: I might not understand what you mean. What i thought you want to say is that
$\mathcal O_\lambda h = \Box h - \lambda h $ is the equation of motion you are going to solve. But the EoM the autor is using is $\Box h - \lambda h^2$ neglecting the source, which is quadratic in $h$. I am confused ...

Comment: Ohh my bad I didn't notice the square I'll edit